# Python: Formatting and counting tuples

Tags: python, formatting, nlp, tuples

I have a tuples of unigrams, bigrams and trigrams which look like this:

```
('be',)
('true',)
('But',)
('I',)
('And', 'but')
('but', 'my')
('my', 'Noble')
('For', 'thy', 'escape')
('thy', 'escape', 'would')
('escape', 'would', 'teach')
('would', 'teach', 'me')
```

I need to find all duplicates, delete all but 1, and format them to look like this:

```
I 2
am 2
STOP 2
I am 2
am Sam 1
Sam I 1
Sam STOP 1
* Sam 1
* I 1
am STOP 1
* * I 1
* I am 1
I am Sam 1
am Sam STOP 1
```

The number at the end if how many duplicates there are and the asterisk's mean that it is after a period which is replaced with .

Heres my code so far:

```
with open(file, "r") as filestring:
data = filestring.read().replace('\n', '').replace(',', ' ').replace('.', '    <STOP>').replace("'", '').replace(':', ' ')
txtlist = data.split()
uni = zip(*[txtlist[i:] for i in range(1)])
bi = zip(*[txtlist[i:] for i in range(2)])
tri = zip(*[txtlist[i:] for i in range(3)])
with open("output.txt", "w") as myfile:
    for item in uni:
        myfile.write(str(item)+"\n")
    for item in bi:
        myfile.write(str(item)+"\n")
    for item in tri:
        myfile.write(str(item)+"\n")
```

Comment: Your current input either has `am` nor `Sam` nor `STOP`, so how do you end up with your that result?

Comment: its just a example how i want it to be formated

Comment: Which are the duplicates the tokens inside the ngrams or the tuples?

Comment: An easy way to remove duplicates (or avoid them in the first place) is to add them to a `set`. If you want to count unique hashable objects (e.g. tuples), use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (or just roll your own from a `dict` or `collections.defaultdict`).

Comment: the tokens inside the n grams so if am Sam is repeated 5 times then it would show as am Sam 5